# What makes Victor Wembanyama good

Tags: basketball, nba

On his [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Wembanyama) ([curent revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Victor_Wembanyama&oldid=1156904664)) it says he is in LIGA fn but looking at his stats it's .348 fg % and 6.5 ppg.  What makes him good because those stats looks really bad especially for a league that's not NBA or Euroleague?  Has he played in G league or similar competition and dominated?

Comment: The article on the [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Wembanyama) ([current revision](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Victor_Wembanyama&oldid=204614794)) seems to have more stats.
Unlike the current revision of the article on English Wikipedia, it contains stats for 2022–23 season, not only 2021–22.